# Factors to consider to take a health insurance policy in India

Tags: india, health-insurance

I am interested to know about the Health insurance policies in India. I am Single and my age is 24. I would like to cover it up for my parents too. (They are in their 50s)

I would like to know what are the factors/dependencies which I should keep in my mind before taking up a policy for my family.

It would be better if the policy provider supports online transaction, since it will make my life easy for the payment. (I heard for some policies we have to manually go there and make payment).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea : updated my question.

Comment: Your prime consideration should be the settlement rate of the insurance company. As mentioned below, do read the fine prints very finely. Apart from very set claims (for instance maternity), the insurance companies downright reject claims or pay ridiculously laughable little on your actual bills(if it is not cashless) and just laughably little on cashless. If your employer provides for health insurance, they will also provide a cover for your parents, you could enquire. If you do buy a policy, make sure it covers you for life, not just till 60-70 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most companies allow online subscriptions. Typically the policies are valid only for an year and have to be renewed every year. You would need to determine the coverage amount required, also read the fine print on "Existing illness" quite a few times the claim would get rejected on this basis. Also there would be a time period before some of the other procedures are covered. Look for the hospital tie-up's for cash-less claim as its more easier.

Even if the company you work for provides for an Health insurance, its advisable to have one on your own as it will cater to scenarios where you are out of job for a period of time.